# webpack import files dynamically while build

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, ts-loader, imageloader

I have webpack + typescript project that has about 1000 images. I also have a file that describes this images like this:

```
[{
  code: 'imageACode',
  alt: 'imageAAlt',
  source: './pathToA.jpg'
}]
```

Same code for B,C,D and other 997 images I got. At the end of the day on client side that should generate html below:

```
<img src="/static/pathToA.jpg" alt="imageAAlt"/>
```

And I also use `imageACode` to replace some html code to that image (whatever).

Ok the simplest way I can do this is:

```
import a from "../assets/images/pathToA.jpg"

{
  code: 'imageACode',
  alt: 'imageAAlt',
  source: a
}
```

Is there more elegant way like so:

```
{
  code: 'imageACode',
  alt: 'imageAAlt',
  source: import '../assets/images/pathToA.jpg'
}
```

Or probably some kind of forEach that webpack should run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lot of assets and you don't want to manually import them, you can use [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context).

This is the simple example that might work in your case:

```
const images = require.context('../assets/images/', false, /\.jpg$/)
const descriptions = images.keys().map(images).map(source => ({
    code: 'code',
    alt: 'alt',
    source
})
```